# how to configure omnetpp5.4.1 while there is qt5 problem

Tags: matlab, qt

Hello all and hope I find a solution here.
I am trying to use **omnetpp-5.4.1** and I already installed qt@5 on Macbook pro.
However I am trying to configure omnet, but this error keeps popping:

```
checking for Qt5 with CFLAGS=" -std=c++11   -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/qt@5/5.15.8_3/include -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/qt@5/5.15.8_3/include/QtCore -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/qt@5/5.15.8_3/include/QtGui -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/qt@5/5.15.8_3/include/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/qt@5/5.15.8_3/include/QtOpenGL -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/qt@5/5.15.8_3/include/QtPrintSupport   -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/qt@5/5.15.8_3/include -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/qt@5/5.15.8_3/include/QtCore -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/qt@5/5.15.8_3/include/QtGui -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/qt@5/5.15.8_3/include/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/qt@5/5.15.8_3/include/QtOpenGL -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/qt@5/5.15.8_3/include/QtPrintSupport" LIBS="-lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lQt5Widgets -lQt5PrintSupport -lQt5OpenGL -L/usr/local/Cellar/qt@5/5.15.8_3/lib -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/Cellar/qt@5/5.15.8_3/lib"... no
checking for Qt5 with CFLAGS=" -std=c++11   -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/qt@5/5.15.8_3/include -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/qt@5/5.15.8_3/include/QtCore -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/qt@5/5.15.8_3/include/QtGui -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/qt@5/5.15.8_3/include/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/qt@5/5.15.8_3/include/QtOpenGL -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/qt@5/5.15.8_3/include/QtPrintSupport   -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/qt@5/5.15.8_3/include -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/qt@5/5.15.8_3/include/QtCore -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/qt@5/5.15.8_3/include/QtGui -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/qt@5/5.15.8_3/include/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/qt@5/5.15.8_3/include/QtOpenGL -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/qt@5/5.15.8_3/include/QtPrintSupport" LIBS="-lQtGui5 -lQtCore5 -lQtWidgets5 -lQtPrintSupport5 -lQtOpenGL5"... no
checking for Qt5 with CFLAGS=" -std=c++11   -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/qt@5/5.15.8_3/include -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/qt@5/5.15.8_3/include/QtCore -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/qt@5/5.15.8_3/include/QtGui -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/qt@5/5.15.8_3/include/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/qt@5/5.15.8_3/include/QtOpenGL -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/qt@5/5.15.8_3/include/QtPrintSupport   -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/qt@5/5.15.8_3/include -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/qt@5/5.15.8_3/include/QtCore -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/qt@5/5.15.8_3/include/QtGui -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/qt@5/5.15.8_3/include/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/qt@5/5.15.8_3/include/QtOpenGL -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/qt@5/5.15.8_3/include/QtPrintSupport" LIBS="-L/Users/sarah/omnetpp-5.4.1/tools/macosx/lib -F/Users/sarah/omnetpp-5.4.1/tools/macosx/lib -framework QtGui -framework QtCore -framework QtWidgets -framework QtPrintSupport -framework QtOpenGL"... no
configure: error: Cannot build Qt apps, probably due to missing or too old Qt packages. Make sure Qt development packages are installed and newer than Qt 5.4. You can disable Qtenv by setting the WITH_QTENV variable to "no" in configure.user.
```

I uninstalled qt5 and reinstalled it.
I changed the paths to qt5 inside the zshrc file.

Nothing is working.